# MultitenantContainer based on multilevel container's tree

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac

In my multitenant application I have three kinds of services:

- common for the full parts of the application
- common for 90% of tenants
- specific for some tenants

So I would like to have a three level container's tree.
An idea is to have a specific `MultitenantContainer` implementation choosing (according the tenantId) the parent container on which `BeginLifetimeScope` is called into the `ConfigureTenant` method. Unfortunatly `ConfigureTenant` is not virtual (and `ApplicationContainer` is private).

Any idea ?

Comment: Is there a reason "common for the full parts of the application" and "common for 90% of tenants" isn't the same thing?

Comment: Some tenants correspond to administration functions and use specific controllers. The other tenants use all the other controllers. If I have 1000 tenants I would like to avoid calling 990 times AddControllers.

Comment: That's my question, though - invert it so the default is non-admin and only register admin overrides for those special 10. Why the default setup isn't for the 990 with overrides for the special few is unclear.